# How to prevent multiple looped outputs from being called all at once in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

I am looping through table tds and each cell on the bottom row is a business description with a ...Read More link that opens a modal.  When I click on one it doesn't just open the modal for that cell but all of them and starts from the last one oddly enough.  Please see this video for a demo:

https://youtu.be/M_EDh_jAWaw

Here is the code:

```
  state = {
    showModal: false
  };

  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState({showModal: true});
    console.log('showModal: ', this.state.showModal);
  }
```

And:

```
  <tr style={{height: '132px'}}>
    {assignedServiceProviders.map((provider, index) => {
      return (
        <td key={index}>
          <Truncate lines={5} ellipsis={<span>... <a onClick={this.toggleModal} key={index}>Read more</a></span>}>
            {provider.description} asfasfdadfdas 46465464 adaddafafdadf 4654564564564 adsadfdafafdfd
          </Truncate>
          <If condition={this.state.showModal}>
            <AutomaticModalTrigger modal={businessDescriptionModal(provider.description)} key={index}>
              <span style={{ display: 'none' }} />
            </AutomaticModalTrigger>
          </If>
        </td>);
    })}
  </tr>
```

When I click on a link it just needs to just open the corresponding business description only and not any of the others!  Does anyone know how to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Maybe have a showModal state for each modal, or have them be keys on a showModal object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are creating multiple instances of modals when you are looping over your *assignedServiceProviders*. I dont think you need the multiple instances since you will open only one at a time.

When you are setting the state of modal to *showModal*. You are actually setting state on all the instances of the generated modals. Hence you end up opening multiple modals.
You should ideally have just one modal and pass data to your modal.

You can do this:

First, Move the modal out of the loop so that you have only one instance of it.

Pass data to:

```
 <a>onClick={() => this.toggleModal(provider.description)} key={index}>Read more</a>
```

Lastly, in toggleModal function first set the *description* then open modal.

This way all your *ReadMore* links will end up calling the same modal instance. But with different descriptions. Once you set the description you can rerender your component with the already existing *showModal* state.

Here is a small example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: false,
      description: ''
    }
    this.list = [{description: 'desc1'}, {description: 'desc2'}];
  }

  onAnchorClick({description},event){
    this.setState({description, showModal: true});
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.list.map((obj, idx) => <div key={idx}>
          <a onClick={this.onAnchorClick.bind(this, obj)}>Read More</a>
        </div>)}

        <div style={{display: !this.state.showModal ? 'none' : 'block'}}>
          <h3>Description: {this.state.description}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

window.onload = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```